# How to transform a matrix of vertices using a 4x4 matrix?

Tags: c++, geometry, linear-algebra, eigen

I have an input of `MatrixXd` where each **row** represent a **vertex**. I need to **transform** all of those vertices with an input of `Matrix4d` **transformation**.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double arrVertices[] = {
        -1.0 , -1.0 , -1.0 ,
        1.0 , -1.0 , -1.0 ,
        1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 ,
        -1.0 , 1.0 , -1.0 ,
        -1.0 , -1.0 , 1.0 ,
        1.0 , -1.0 , 1.0 ,
        1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 ,
        -1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0
    };

    double arrTransformation[] = {
        0.85656139265934328,
        -0.43936858626129838,
        -0.27066182961813096,
        0.00000000000000000,
        0.51460157667407691,
        0.76645256154673991,
        0.38436400479622890,
        0.00000000000000000,
        0.038571983226693918,
        -0.46851437150336084,
        0.88261344075692039,
        0.00000000000000000,
        3.8451662635348320,
        -11.029392777345908,
        19.898165291232520,
        1.0000000000000000
    };

    Eigen::MatrixXd vertices = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 3>>(arrVertices);
    Eigen::Matrix4d transformation = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>>(arrTransformation);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.rows(); ++i) {
        vertices.row(i) = transformation * vertices.row(i); // This causes "INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to multiply them?

Comment: Yes. I have tried `vertices.row(i) = transformation * vertices.row(i);` which gives me `INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT`. I'm bad with math, so bear with me.

Comment: I dont know eigen, but I know that you have better chances getting an answer if you show what you tried and how it failed and if you ask a question instead of just stating what you want.

Comment: I just edited it following your suggestions.

Comment: How do you expect a row of 3 elements to be transformed by a 4x4 matrix? This doesn't really make sense algebraically

Comment: @shananton if I add a fourth column to the `vertices.row(i)`, I get `YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES`.

Comment: Could you provide the new code?

Comment: Oh, actually, I'm guessing the new error refers to your multiplication - it should be `vertices.row(i) * transformation`, not the other way around. (you can only multiply a 1x4 row by a 4x4 matrix if the row is on the left)

Answer (score 1):

From your description of your matrix it looks like you're trying to apply an [affine transform](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/index.htm) (rotation + translation) to a set of vertices. I encourage you to read the math explanation in the link above or [this one](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-3d-matrix-transforms-with-pixijs-c76da3f8bd8) but here's a quick TLDR :

Your transform matrix does not represent only a *linear* transform. A linear transform (for example, a rotation ***R***) is represented by a 3x3 matrix. You can multiply a 3D vertex ***v*** by a 3x3 matrix to get the transformed vertex such as ***v'*** = ***R***.***v***

Here you want to apply two transforms : a rotation ***R*** (3x3 matrix) and a translation **t**, i.e. you want ***v'*** = ***R***.***v*** + ***t***

In many computer graphics applications this kind of transform is [represented in a 4x4 matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) where

- the top 3x3 elements is the rotation matrix
- the last column is the translation vector
- the last row is [0,0,0,1]

This is exactly how your matrix is structured :

```
 0.856561  0.514602  0.038572   3.84517
-0.439369  0.766453 -0.468514  -11.0294
-0.270662  0.384364  0.882613   19.8982
        0         0         0         1
```

The math works out if you multiply this 4x4 transform matrix with the vertex. This won't work with the 3D vertex itself (you can't multiply a 4x4 matrix with a 3D vector). For the trick to work you need to add a 1 as the 4th coordinate (this is called [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) ; you can try checking out the maths to see that it does the rotation and the translation.)

Fortunately there's a [`Transform`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html) class in Eigen that does that for you. You need to create a Transform from a 4x4 matrix and multiply directly 3D vectors (it does the homogenous coordinates conversion under the hood). Note that you need to put the vertices in columns for this to work, so we'll transpose your matrix.

```
 Eigen::Matrix<double,8, 3> vertices = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 8, 3>>(arrVertices);
 Eigen::Matrix4d transformation_matrix = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>>(arrTransformation);

 // Create a 3D affine transform
 Eigen::Transform<double, 3, Eigen::Affine> transform(transformation_matrix);
 // Transpose the vertices to put them in columns and transform them :
 cout << transform * vertices.transpose() << endl;
```